# javascript toggle to show only one div at a time in a group

Tags: javascript, html, css, toggle

The code below toggles individual divs correctly, however, it shows enabled divs below each other as I toggle but I need to "**show only one at a time**". Any idea?

```js
function toggle_visibility(id) {
  var e = document.getElementById(id);
  if (e.style.display == 'block')
    e.style.display = 'none';
  else
    e.style.display = 'block';
}
```

```html
<ul class="post-advanced-menu">
  <li><a href="#" onclick="toggle_visibility('source');">Source</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" onclick="toggle_visibility('share');">Share</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" onclick="toggle_visibility('report');">Report</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="post-advanced-content">
   <div id="source" style="display: none;">Source</div>
   <div id="share" style="display: none;">Share</div>
   <div id="report" style="display: none;">Report</div>
</div>
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

You should hide other Elements before visible the selected one.

```js
function toggle_visibility(id) {
  const target = document.getElementById(id);
  if (!target) return;

  // Hide all other div elements.
  const divs = document.querySelectorAll('.div');
  for (const div of divs) {
    div.style.display = 'none';
  }

  // Show selected one
  target.style.display = 'block';
}
```

```css
div {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}

#source {
  background: red;
}

#share {
  background: blue;
}

#report {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<ul class="post-advanced-menu">
  <li><a href="#" onclick="toggle_visibility('source');">Source</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" onclick="toggle_visibility('share');">Share</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" onclick="toggle_visibility('report');">Report</a></li>
</ul>

<!-- Source -->
<div id="source" class="div" style="display: none;"></div>

<!-- Share -->
<div id="share" class="div" style="display: none;"></div>

<!-- Report -->
<div id="report" class="div" style="display: none;"></div>
```

Comment: I just noticed something else, I guess this js is applying display none to other things as well, thats why my page gets blank. I guess I just need to specific divs to hide. Thank you mate

Comment: @Designer yes you should add a class name for it

Comment: dinindu. You edited my asnwer and removed a functionaility. Why?

Comment: @Azametzin Did you lose anything? I just improved your answer, that's all.

Comment: No, you didn't. If you test the code before and after, you're going to see that before you could hide an already opened div, and now you can't. I also explained it in the second line of my description.

Comment: @Azametzin not sure! Let's roll back then.

Comment: Thanks! this works :) It doesnt hide already opened div though.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to hide other items before click.
It also hides the clicked div if it's visible.

You can add a class for each div. For example: `class="item"`, in order to help in the process.

```
<ul class="post-advanced-menu">
  <li><a href="#" onclick="toggle_visibility('source');">Source</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" onclick="toggle_visibility('share');">Share</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" onclick="toggle_visibility('report');">Report</a></li>
</ul>

<!-- Source -->
<div id="source" class="item" style="display: none;">1</div>

<!-- Share -->
<div id="share" class="item" style="display: none;">2</div>

<!-- Report -->
<div id="report" class="item" style="display: none;">3</div>
```

```
function toggle_visibility(id) {
  var e = document.getElementById(id);
  if (e.style.display == 'block') {
    e.style.display = 'none'
  } else {
    document.querySelectorAll('.item').forEach(function(div) {
       div.style.display = 'none';
    })
    e.style.display = 'block';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend unobtrusive script using class and data attributes:

```js
window.addEventListener("load",
  () => document.querySelectorAll(".post-advanced-menu").forEach(
    ele => ele.addEventListener("click",
      e => {
        var tgt = e.target;
        var id = tgt.getAttribute("data-id");
        document.querySelectorAll(".toggle").forEach(
          ele => ele.style.display = ele.id == id ? "block" : "none")
      })
  )
)
```

```css
.toggle {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<ul class="post-advanced-menu">
  <li><a href="#" data-id="source">Source</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" data-id="share">Share</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" data-id="report">Report</a></li>
</ul>

<!-- Source -->
<div id="source" class="toggle">Source</div>

<!-- Share -->
<div id="share" class="toggle">Share</div>

<!-- Report -->
<div id="report" class="toggle">Report</div>
```